# Is it possible to induce Mathematica to chop off parts of Graphics objects that exist outside of a Frame?

Tags: plotting, graphics

I am running *Mathematica* 7.  In a `Graphics` environment I am setting `Frame -> True` (and using `FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}` and `PlotLabel -> "My Title"`, etc) so that I can see length scales in `Graphics` environments.

Suppose that I create a `Disk` of radius `0.9`, centered at the origin.  I have set `PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}`.  The result looks nice:

> ```
> Graphics[{
>   Cyan, Disk[{0, 0}, 0.9]
>   },
>  PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, Frame -> True, 
>  FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, PlotLabel -> "My Disk"]
> ```
>
> [image: Disk 1]

Now, however, suppose that I want to create a `Disk` that is not entirely contained in `Frame`.  For example, I might leave `PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}` and increase the `Disk` radius from `0.9` to `1.2`.  However, in the resulting image, the `Disk` goes beyond the boundaries of the `Frame`:

> ```
> Graphics[{
>   Cyan, Disk[{0, 0}, 1.2]
>   },
>  PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, Frame -> True, 
>  FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, PlotLabel -> "My Disk"]
> ```
>
> [image: Disk 2]

Is there any way that I can direct *Mathematica* to chop off parts of the `Graphics` objects that exist outside of the `Frame`?  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If I have understood correctly then `PlotRangeClipping -> True` is what you need:

```
Graphics[{Cyan, Disk[{0, 0}, 1.2]}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, PlotLabel -> "My Disk", 
 PlotRangeClipping -> True]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Though not strictly a way to clip graphics, a similar result for a disk can be obtained with `RegionPlot` which automatically frames and clips regions.

```
r = 1.2;
RegionPlot[x^2+y^2 <= r^2, {x,-r,r}, {y,-r,r},
PlotRange->{{-1,1},{-1,1}}, PlotLabel->"My Disk"]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: The reason is still the same as in Mike's answer :) `RegionPlot` just has it set to `True` by default. See `Options[RegionPlot, PlotRangeClipping]` and `Options[Graphics, PlotRangeClipping]`