# How to crop graphics outside PlotRange with Show?

Tags: graphics

Is there an option or method to prevent `Graphics` from being displayed outside the `PlotRange` region?

The problem is illustrated below: the gray lines are linear regressors and are being combined using `Show` with additional graphics.

The spill-over occurs both with and without `PlotLabel` set and only on the Top portion of the frame. But as I explain below it is more noticeable with `PlotLabel` set.

[image]

The same `PlotRange -> {{0, 15}, {0, 175}}` is set twice, once in the main scatterplot that renders the frame (it is built up with `Graphics` elements rather than a `ListPlot`), and also in the call to `Show` which combines the scatterplot, highlighted points and the regressors.

But I've also tried removing `PlotRange` independently in either, with no change in results.

Removing `PlotLabel` causes the out-of-bounds portion of the lines to be considerably shortened but still visibly outside the boxes.

Comment: related : http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17700/5467

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must add the option `PlotRangeClipping -> True`

```
Show[...,PlotRangeClipping -> True]
```

Explanation of your results :

- `Show[gr1,gr2 ...]` take the options of the first graphic in the list, gr1 here.
- Concerning the scatterplot, `Graphics[]` has by default `PlotRangeClipping -> False`
- Concerning the line, `Plot[]` has by default `PlotRangeClipping -> True`

So if `gr1` is the Graphic with the scatterplot, the behavior you see is fully explained.